# React Native & Firestore: Property 'auth' does not exist on type 'typeof / error object unknown

Tags: typescript, firebase, react-native

I am using typescript along with Firebase and React Native.

I was working on my signup screen and I imported firebase like this:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
```

Then on my `onSignUp` function I got this:

```js
onSignUp = async () => {
  if (this.state.email && this.state.password) {
    try {
      const response = await firebase
        .auth()
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password);
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.code == 'auth/email-already-in-use') {
        Alert.alert('Signup Error', 'User already exist!', [
          {
            text: 'Ok',
          },
        ]);
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Visual Studio Code is complaining about the `auth` on `await firebase.auth()` it says `Property 'auth' does not exist on type 'typeof`.

Additionally, it's also complaining about the `error.code` and it saying `Object is of type 'unknown'.ts(2571)` not sure what it meant and been stuck for awhile.

Here's my complete code:

```js
export interface Props {}
interface State {
  email: string;
  password: any;
  isLoading: boolean;
}

export default class LoginScreen extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      email: '',
      password: '',
      isLoading: false,
    };
  }

  onLogin = () => {};

  onSignUp = async () => {
    if (this.state.email && this.state.password) {
      try {
        const response = await firebase
          .auth()
          .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            this.state.email,
            this.state.password
          );
      } catch (error) {
        if (error.code == 'auth/email-already-in-use') {
          Alert.alert('Signup Error', 'User already exist!', [
            {
              text: 'Ok',
            },
          ]);
        }
      }
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput
          placeholder="Your Email"
          keyboardType="email-address"
          autoCorrect={false}
          style={styles.txtInput}
          onChangeText={(email) => this.setState(email)}
        />
        <TextInput
          placeholder="Your Password"
          secureTextEntry
          style={styles.txtInput}
          onChangeText={(password) => this.setState(password)}
        />
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btnLog} onPress={this.onLogin}>
          <Text style={styles.logTxt}>Login</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Any idea what's causing the `firebase.auth()` and `error.code`? Please help.

**UPDATE**: I tried following the v9 guide using async await but still not working:

```js
import {initializeApp} from 'firebase/app';
import {firebaseConfig} from '../config/config';
import {getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword} from 'firebase/auth';

export interface Props {}
interface State {
  email: string;
  password: any;
  isLoading: boolean;
}

export default class LoginScreen extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      email: '',
      password: '',
      isLoading: false,
    };

    this.initialFirebase();
  }

  initialFirebase = () => {
    initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  };

  auth = getAuth(this.initialFirebase);

  onLogin = () => {};

  onSignUp = async () => {
    if (this.state.email && this.state.password) {
      try {
        const response = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          auth,
          this.state.email,
          this.state.password,
        );
      } catch (error) {
        if (error.code == 'auth/email-already-in-use') {
          Alert.alert('Signup Error', 'User already exist!', [
            {
              text: 'Ok',
            },
          ]);
        }
      }
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have the `new Modular SDK V9` which uses a new syntax. If want to use existing syntax (v8) then change the imports to `compat` version:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app'
import 'firebase/compat/auth'
// import 'firebase/compat/[SERVICE]'
```

I would recommend [upgrading to new SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade) since it has certain performance benefits. You can try using this syntax:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app"
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth"

const app = initializeApp({...config})

const auth = getAuth(app)


// in onSignUp
createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
  .then((userCredential) => {
    // Signed in 
    const user = userCredential.user;
    // ...
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    const errorCode = error.code;
    const errorMessage = error.message;
    // ..
  });
```

You can refer to [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth) for learning more about the new SDK.

Comment: Thank you. How do I do it using new Modular SDK V9?

Comment: `error.code` says something about `Object is of type 'unknown'.ts(2571)` is this also related with that?

Comment: @AichiGarcia can you try my updated answer? Also keep the documentation linked above open. It has both v8 and v9 syntaxes side by side .

Comment: I updated my question above. I tried following your code snippet using async await. But still its not working. Any idea where I've missed? Sorry I am newbie.

Comment: See screenshot: https://prnt.sc/1tc4h1e

Comment: @AichiGarcia can you hover on `this.initialFirebase` and share screenshot of what it says?

Comment: `Argument of type '() => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FirebaseApp'.
  Type '() => void' is missing the following properties from type 'FirebaseApp': options, automaticDataCollectionEnabledt`

Comment: @AichiGarcia it seems the code can run before `this.initialFirebase` actually has the value of FirebaseApp... just try `getAuth()` with no params... make sure initializeApp has run before that